# How to conditionally remove characters and preserve a text in between?

Tags: regex, sed

How could sed or another POSIX command be used to remove the braces but only when we encounter `"codeBlock":{"_id":{"varying24characters"}`.  There may be multiple matches with this condition in the line and I want to avoid removing the braces on something that looks similar like the smoreBlock.

Input (a single line)

```
test,"codeBlock":{"_id":{"4c9d4e1fe2c101000138eb4b"},morestuff,"smoreBlock":{"_id":{"6c9d4e1fe2c101000138eb4b"},hey,stuff,test,"codeBlock":{"_id":{"7c9d4e1fe7c101111138eb4b"},otherstuff
```

Desired output

```
test,"codeBlock":{"_id":"4c9d4e1fe2c101000138eb4b",morestuff,"smoreBlock":{"_id":{"6c9d4e1fe2c101000138eb4b"},hey,stuff,test,"codeBlock":{"_id":"7c9d4e1fe7c101111138eb4b",otherstuff
```

I've been banging my head reading about sed backreferences and can't even get close to what I'm looking for.  Unfortunately this is not homework.  I could write a small program to brute force through it but I know there has got to be a way for sed, awk, or perl to handle this.  Planning to run this on a RHEL7 or CENTOS7 host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think it the other way, match both needed and unneeded together, but keep former in capturing groups. Thus you can replace whole match with only needed parts.

```
sed 's/\("codeBlock":{"_id":\){\("[0-9a-f]\{24\}"\)}/\1\2/g' file
```

Or, if you have GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/("codeBlock":\{"_id":)\{("[0-9a-f]{24}")\}/\1\2/g' file
```

both yield:

```
test,"codeBlock":{"_id":"4c9d4e1fe2c101000138eb4b",morestuff,"smoreBlock":{"_id":{"6c9d4e1fe2c101000138eb4b"},hey,stuff,test,"codeBlock":{"_id":"7c9d4e1fe7c101111138eb4b",otherstuff
```

Comment: Both solutions work and yield the same result.  This is simple and elegant and most importantly it actually makes sense!   Good catch on the a-f vs a-z.